# "true parameters" in the example of election

Tags: terminology, parameterization

[A wiki post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) says

> In statistics, a confidence interval (CI) is a type of estimate computed from the statistics of the observed data. This proposes a range of plausible values for an unknown parameter (for example, the mean). The interval has an associated confidence level that the **true parameter** is in the proposed range.

Does "true parameter" means the following?

Assume there are two candidates A and B in an election, a hundred million people will vote. #voters_A of them support A, #voters_B of them support B, #voters_N of them support neither.

$\frac{\text{#voters}_A}{\text{a hundred million}}$, 
$\frac{\text{#voters}_B}{\text{a hundred million}}$, $\frac{\text{#voters}_N}{\text{a hundred million}}$, are the **true parameters**, which are **population proportion**.

A hundred million votes is the **population**.

If we randomly ask 1,000 of the them who do they support, what we will get is the **sample**.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "parameters" of a distribution are values that are used to specify the distribution.  These generally depend on the assumed form of the population and the sampling mechanism.  In this case, if you use simple random sampling without replacement (SRSWR) then the three values you have specified (or indeed, any two of them) are sufficient to determine the probability distribution of the sample values.  Thus, those three values are indeed valid "parameters" in this case.  The "true parameters" are simply the true values of those parameters, which is something you would estimate from the data.

Note also that there are multiple different ways you could validly set the parameters.  You could either use the proportions (as you have done) or you could use the raw counts.  Either method would give you a set of parameters that fully determine the probability distribution for the sample values.

What you have written in your question is mostly correct.  The one quibble I have with it is that you need to *be consistent* as to what a population unit actually is.  In this problem, you can validly set the population to consist either of voters, or their votes, but you should not equivocate between these two things.  You initially say that the population is the "votes" but then later you say that "we randomly ask 1,000 of them who they support".  So who did you ask --- the votes?